# Why can't assign multiple users to task created from record page

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, tasks, configuration, activities

When I create a task from Task tab, I can assign task to multiple users.

[image]

But when it comes to any record page, and I try to add new task from related list, Salesforce not allows to add multiple users in Assigned To field.

[image]

I found there's an idea [Cannot assign multiple users to task from record page in lightning](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LoHoQAK) in IdeaExchange. Why salesforce not delivering this feature for record page as well? Do I need to go for lightning component to achieve this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest you using related list single with object name Open Activities. It will allow to select multiple users on record pages also. It will have another advantage of giving ability choosing the record type before creating task and events. Read more here:-
[Open Activities and Activity History Related List in Lightning Experience](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/02/04/open-activities-and-activity-history-related-list-in-lightning-experience/)

[image]

[image]